# How to send email using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have data contained in column A to H. The data in column A are email addresses. I put a check box in another cell. What I want is when I tick the check box it proceeds to send email to the email account placed in last row column A. But the below code only works for cell A1.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()

    Dim Email As String

    Row = 1
    Email = Sheet1.Cells(Row, 1)
    Do Until Sheet1.Cells(Row, 1) = ""
        Row = Row + 1
    Loop

    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = Email
        .Subject = score
        .HTMLBody = "This is a contain of Email Message"
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: My guess is that you messed the order of statements: first you need `Do Until … Loop` to find the last row, and only then to assign `Email = …`. Your current code just picks Email from R1C1 unconditionally.

Answer (score 3):

In your section below, where you are trying to get the last row and then the email from that cell:

```
Row = 1
Email = Sheet1.Cells(Row, 1)
Do Until Sheet1.Cells(Row, 1) = ""
    Row = Row + 1
Loop
```

you are taking the `Email` from the first row, and after in the `Do Until` loop you are checking for the last row, **but not modifying** the `Email` variable.

**Resolve**: There is no need to have a loop to find the last row with a valid email address in Column A, you can simply find it with the following lines below:

```
Dim LastRow As Long

' get last row with data in Column A (don't skip blank cells in the middle)
LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Email = Sheet1.Range("A" & LastRow).Value
```

The rest of your code works just fine.

Comment: Dear Experts, Many thanks for your knowledge sharing

Comment: @taufik  please mark as answer (click on the **V** next to my answer)