# Paste a value according to some criteria in outlook

Tags: excel, vba, email, criteria, paste

According to the criteria "copy the filtered ranges" shall be pasted into an e-mail with the text stated in "strText" both as html. If the criteria is not fullfiled then the text stated in "strText2" is taken only and pasted into the e-mail.

The issue is that only the text in "strText" is copied into the E-Mail without the copied range. Secondly, in the "Else" line the code ".HTMLBody = strText2" wouldnt as it goes directly to the sheet.

(the "Function GetBoiler..."  has been excluded due to simplicity)

```
Sub Mail_Klicken()

Dim olApp As Object

Dim datDatum As Date
Dim StrBody As String
Dim intZeile As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Dim strMailverteilerTo As String
Dim strMailverteilerCC As String
Dim strText As String
Dim strFilename As String
Dim loLetzte As Long

strMailverteilerTo = "dfgdfg@gmx.de


   strText = "<span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:""Arial"",""sans-serif"";color:black'>Hello,<br><br> xxxx:<br><br>"

  strText2 = "<span style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:""Arial"",""sans-serif"";color:black'>hello,<br><br>this is the second text.<br><br>"

 Application.DisplayAlerts = True

 Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

 With olApp.CreateItem(0)

    .to = strMailverteilerTo
    .Subject = "asdf checked"

    strFilename = "Standard"
    If Application.UserName = "wert" Then strFilename = "Signatur allg.1"

    strText = strText & "" & GetBoiler(Environ("appdata")       & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & strFilename & ".htm")


 With Worksheets("Auswertung")
   loLetzte = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
   .Range("$A$7:$D$" & loLetzte).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">0"
If .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count > 1 Then
      .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).Resize(.AutoFilter.Range.Rows.Count - 1). _
      SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Else
    'take only the "strText2"
End If
   .AutoFilterMode = False
End With

.HTMLBody = strText
.Display

End With

Set olApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Where is `strText` assigned a value? Did you set the `BodyFormat` of the message to `olFormatHTML`?

Comment: I have just included the value to strText. I have not set the BodyFormat of the message to olFormatHTML. Would that solve the error message?

Comment: If that is your full `Sub`, you're missing a bunch of code and your immediate error is because you are calling `.HTMLBody` on your *worksheet* in the `With` block. I also don't see anywhere that you are actually creating an email. Finally, your HTML needs to be valid - that is, it needs to include the `<html>` and `body` elements. There are several good examples of how to send email from Excel - [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49645926/4088852) might be a good start.

Comment: I suspect when you are trying to set **`.HTMLBody = strText`**, it's meant to be to outlook and not to your worksheet? because at the moment you are trying to use that with your worksheet and that is not supported. Try creating and outlook object (or reference it)...

Comment: I have included the whole Sub now. And also rephrased the question for a better understanding of my aim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer can be found here: https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail2.htm